# Python QT (PySide) QPushButton stylesheet causing "assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed" error

Tags: python, qt, gtk, pyside

Every time I try to apply a stylesheet to a QPushButton I get the error:

```
(python:21347): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_direction: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed".
```

The error appears twice, but the program still runs fine, and the stylesheet seems to be correctly applied. Here is minimal code which still produces the error:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = QtGui.QWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button")
    button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { color: black }")
    layout.addWidget(button)
    wid.setLayout(layout)
    wid.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Commenting out the button.setStyleSheet eliminates the error message. If it makes a difference, I'm running this under Xubuntu 13.10 using the libraries from the repo.

The error obviously isn't actually a serious problem since the code runs as expected without trouble, but I'd really like to get rid of the error messages!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it is specific for your platform. There are many bug reports with same errors. But try to set cleanlooks style to your app. Something like this:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
#QCleanlooksStyle
app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
```

Or use command line:

```
./myapp -style cleanlooks
```

Comment: Ahh! Thank you, this definitely fixes the bug.

My one concern is that doesn't this override the OS style? I'd really like my program to use the OS look and feel where possible. I don't suppose you know how to identify the platform that this bug is on so that I can only set the style then?

Comment: @Julian Sorry, but I have no idea. I found that this trick use many people who had same error.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out a work around anyway - if I just set the style on the button: button.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks")), then it still clears up the bug but doesn't affect the overall look and feel. Since my button is totally customized anyway, it's no problem!